# How to list all keywords from a .robot file which have no test cases

Tags: python, robotframework

Problem statement:
I have a .robot file which contains a lot of keywords. this is a higher level robot file which does not contains any test cases.
I want to list all the keywords name.

What i tried so far ?

```
from robot.parsing.model import TestData
suite = TestData(parent=None,source="Track2_Keywords.robot")
```

it gives error

> raise NoTestsFound('File has no tests or tasks.')
>   robot.parsing.populators.NoTestsFound: File has no tests or tasks.

also i tried:

```
from robot.parsing.model import KeywordTable
suite = KeywordTable("Track2_Keywords.robot")
for item in suite:
...     print (item.name)
```

but its empty.

Comment: I'm assuming you're going to be using this list to drive documentation around the keywords you have. Have you had a look at the libdoc section of the user guide? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-documentation-tool-libdoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to use the `ResourceFile` model rather than `TestData` or `KeywordTable`. Second, you must call the `populate` method to get the keywords to be visible. It is the `populate` method that actually reads the file and imports the keywords.

```
from robot.parsing.model import ResourceFile

rf = ResourceFile("Track2_Keywords.robot")
rf.populate()
for kw in rf.keywords:
    print(kw.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what is your goal. If the file does not contain tests, then it is a Resource file. In this case you can add a dummy test case like for example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Dummy Test
    No Operation
```

This way, your code should not complaint about missing tests.

--
If you want to find non used keywords in a test suite, you can use that existing feature in RIDE (https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/).

Comment: I don't think asking them to convert a resource file into a test suite is a good solution. The file ceases to be a resource file and thus can't be imported.

Comment: My proposal was to be able to have success in running the code, not for a permanent or production solution.